# PHP modify TXT file

Tags: php, file, parsing

I have a ID.txt file that looks like this:

```
"http://something.net/something-ak/41389_718783565_1214898307_q.jpg"
"http://something.net/something-ak/372142_106502518141813_1189943482_q.jpg"
and so on
```

I want to use PHP to open the file and remove everything before the first " _ " and everything after the second " _ " so I wind up with this:

```
718783565
106502518141813
and so on
```

Thing is I don't really know how to do that.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?PHP
$file_handle = fopen("ID.txt", "rb");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
$parts = explode('\n', $line_of_text);

// Remove everything before the first "_" and everything after the last "_".
// echo the line
}

fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Can someone help me fille in the blanks?

Comment: Try to split the filename at "_" and from this result (it is an array), you have to get the 1 index.

Comment: Do you simply want to GET the string between the first two underscores, or do you actually want to edit the file?

Comment: Are you committed to using PHP to parse the file into the format you want?  Would you be ok with `awk -F"_" '...'` to preprocess the file into the format pretty easily and then the PHP file to read it already processed?

Comment: I want to get the string between the two underscores and insert some lines between them.

Comment: @Yzmir I have no idea what you just suggested is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do, although a regex might be shorter or more efficient:

```
$file_handle = fopen("ID.txt", "rb");
while (!feof($file_handle) )
{
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode("\n", $line_of_text);

    foreach ($parts as $str)
    {
        $str_parts = explode('_', $str); // Split string by _ into an array
        array_shift($str_parts); // Remove first element
        echo current($str_parts)."\n"; // echo current element and newline
        // Same as $str_parts[0]
    }
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/uFbVDtbR

Not a big deal, but `$lines` might be a better variable name there instead of `$parts`.

If you do need to write this back to the file, you can do this:

```
ob_start();
// code used above
$new_content = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents("ID.txt", $new_content);
```

Relevant references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: This doesn't modify the file, which is what the OP requested.

Comment: My downvote is removed, but somebody else doesn't like you.  :)

Comment: I need to remove everything after the second underscore, not the third... would that involve simply repeating the array_pop line?

Comment: I see I missed that, I should've read your example output (now the -1's make sense, I thought you wanted everything between the first and last underscore). 1 sec, will fix.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [file](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) in a loop

```
$content = "";
foreach(file("ID.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line){
    $parts = explode('_', $line);
    $content .=  $parts[1] . "\n";
}
file_put_contents("ID.txt", $content);
```

---

If you want to achieve this by [awk](/questions/tagged/awk),

```
awk -F _ '{print $2}' ID.txt
```

Comment: this doesn't modify the file at all

Comment: @andreas so you want I give home the whole code and he copy it without learning a single bit?

Comment: @Shiplu hey don't need to get all defensive, I'm just telling you what the OP requires, there removed my downvote

Comment: @Madmartigan nice catch. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

preg_match('/(.*?*)(.+?)(*.*)/',$line,$matches);

$matches[2] will give the required string

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<?php
// open files
$file_handle = fopen("ID.txt", "rb");
$new_file_handle = fopen("ID2.txt", "wb");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
  $str = fgets($file_handle);
  $start = strpos($str, '_'); // find first "_"
  $end = strpos($str, '_', $start + 1); // find next "_"
  $newstr = substr($str, $start + 1, $end - $start - 1) . "\n";
  fputs($new_file_handle, $newstr);
}
// close files
fclose($file_handle); 
fclose($new_file_handle);
// rename
rename("ID2.txt", "ID.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$TXT = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/in.txt');
$NewTXT = preg_replace('~^.+/[0-9]+_([0-9]+)_.+?$~mi', '$1', $TXT);
file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/out.txt', $NewTXT);
```

Just rename the .txt files accordingly.